# What is the "server name" in MCPE?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

This may seem like a noob question but if someone could answer it I'd be extremely grateful. When me and my brother try join worlds in MCPE it says to enter the "server name". I honestly dont know what this is could someone please help me?

Answer (score 3):

When asked to define a server connection, there are three fields:

- **Server Name** is a human-friendly name for the server. Treat it as a label that is stored on your phone to help you distinguish servers from each other, especially when it is not using a domain name but rather a raw IP address.
- **Server IP** is the IP or web address of the server that you are connecting to.
- **Port** is the TCP port that the server you're connecting to is running on. If left blank, the games assumes to default port of `19132`.

Answer (score 1):

If you saw "Server name", "Server IP/Address", and "Port", you would be entering the information for a paid server. To play casually with someone, the following conditions will be required:

1. The devices need to be "visible" to each other
2. They need to be connected to the same Wi-Fi network

After these conditions are met...

3. Have one of you open up a world
4. Have the other person press "play" and wait a few seconds

The other person's username, in blue, should appear at the top of your world list. Tap on this and you're playing in multiplayer!

Answer (score 1):

The "server name" does not matter. It's just a label you can enter to recognize the server later if you have a lot of servers added.